# WinPhone Xaml Grid.Background relative path

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm trying to set the background to a windows phone page in Xaml.  I'm probably missing something really obvious but I can't seem to get this to show unless the page and background are in the same folder.  What I want however is my page to be in a views folder and my background to be in a resources folder.  This is what I have at the minute:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="\\Resources\MMCRBackground.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Grid.Background>

    </Grid>
```

There is no error saying that the path doesn't exist?  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory I think you want

```
 <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/MMCRBackground.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

Where the MMCRBackground.png has a build action of Content (not resource) in the properties from the Solution Exporer